# Is it a bad idea to use a different type of paper as continuation paper?

Tags: print-design, paper

I'm doing an identity design for a friend who doesn't have a particularly large budget, so he wants to spend as little as possible on printing.

The first page will need to be printed at a printing shop because it has a full bleed header, but the consecutive pages consist only of the text and the footer with no header.

Would it be noticeable if the first page was good quality paper but for the rest we used slightly different paper? I wouldn't use anything which is too different in thickness. However, apart from thickness will the different textures, textured first and smooth rest, be noticeable?

I ordered a sample kit from the printer so I could see how different it'd be, does anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Would it be noticeable if the first page was good quality paper but for the rest we used slightly different paper?

Probably.

---

Generally you only vary paper types when you are doing a cover and guts kind of publication or print item.

For example a booklet will have a cardstock thick exterior but normal 80lb paper for the interior pages. It really depends on the end product.

Textures can vary from manufacturer to manufacturer and if you don't match them correctly the papers won't match. Usually print products are done on only one media type.

---

Depending on your final product you should use the SAME paper for all pages OR you should do a cover/guts layout and have one thickness for the exterior and another for the interior.